# Error: 30509 -- Bluetooth not available iPad and iPhone GameKit stuff

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth, gamekit

When trying to connect the iPad to the iPhone via bluetooth it stays on the "Looking for other iPhones or iPod touches" screen on both. If i try running the iPhone version on both, they find each other. Is this some sort of restriction? Thanks.

also, im getting:

```
2010-05-22 01:49:52.301 iPadTest[241:207] ********** Loading AX for: com.taptouchclick.iPadTest ************
2010-05-22 01:49:58.366 iPadTest[241:207] BTM: attaching to BTServer
Listening on port 49403
2010-05-22 01:49:58.480 iPadTest[241:207] Error: 30509 -- Bluetooth not available..
2010-05-22 01:49:58.492 iPadTest[241:5403] handleEvents started (2)
2010-05-22 01:49:58.799 iPadTest[241:207] BTM: posting notification BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
2010-05-22 01:49:59.120 iPadTest[241:5403] ~ DNSServiceRegister callback: Ref=180da0, Flags=2, ErrorType=0 name=00cb-qc0A..iPad  regtype=_uv2nevk4u6n9m2._udp. domain=local.
2010-05-22 01:49:59.335 iPadTest[241:5403] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=180bb0, Flags=2, IFIndex=2 (name=[en0]), ErrorType=0 name=00cb-qc0A..iPad  regtype=_uv2nevk4u6n9m2._udp. domain=local.
2010-05-22 01:50:29.201 iPadTest[241:5403] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=180bb0, Flags=0, IFIndex=2 (name=[en0]), ErrorType=0 name=00cb-qc0A..iPad  regtype=_uv2nevk4u6n9m2._udp. domain=local.
2010-05-22 01:50:32.052 iPadTest[241:5403] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=180bb0, Flags=2, IFIndex=1 (name=[lo0]), ErrorType=0 name=00cb-qc0A..iPad  regtype=_uv2nevk4u6n9m2._udp. domain=local.
2010-05-22 01:50:46.379 iPadTest[241:5403] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=180bb0, Flags=0, IFIndex=1 (name=[lo0]), ErrorType=0 name=00cb-qc0A..iPad  regtype=_uv2nevk4u6n9m2._udp. domain=local.
2010-05-22 01:50:52.143 iPadTest[241:5403] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=180bb0, Flags=2, IFIndex=2 (name=[en0]), ErrorType=0 name=00cb-qc0A..iPad  regtype=_uv2nevk4u6n9m2._udp. domain=local.
```

in the console. not sure what that means, but "Error: 30509 -- Bluetooth not available.." scares me. ideas?

Thanks,
TapTouchClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I will need to use sessions and id's if its not the same app running on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

That error occures on device without p2p bluetooth (e.g. iPhone 2G/iPod Touch 1G).

Even if your device supports it, you still will have same error on iOS lower than 3.1 on attempting to start GKSession to discover Wi-Fi peers. (Thats because GameKit supports Wi-Fi since iOS 3.1).